# X tends to zero

Tags: limits

$((\tan(\pi/4+x))^{1/x} - e^2)/x^2$ we have to find the limit as x tends to zero

I started out by writing $\tan(\pi/4+x)$ as $e^{\ln(\tan(\pi/4+x))}$

Can you please help me in what to do next

I don't know much calculus yet so would appreciate if the answers didn't use lhospital

Comment: can you use $$\LaTeX$$ please?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Can you please edit the question I don't know much latex

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner sir now the question has been edited so can you help me on how to solve this

Comment: use the rules of L'Hospital

Answer (score 2):

We start with the expression

$$\lim_{x \to 0}\; \frac{\tan(\pi/4 + x)^{1/x} - e^2}{x^2}$$

As we will see soon, the upper part of the fraction goes to $0$ as $x \to 0$. To see that, you made the right start. Lets just look at

$$\lim_{x \to 0}\; \tan(\pi/4 + x)^{1/x}$$

By using the identity $x = e^{\ln(x)}$ you have already rewritten it to

$$\lim_{x \to 0}\; e^{\ln\left(\tan(\pi/4 + x)^{1/x}\right)}$$

which in term is equal to

$$\lim_{x \to 0}\; e^{\frac{1}{x}\ln\left(\tan(\pi/4 + x)\right)}$$

As such, we will now first look at the limit in the exponent

$$\lim_{x \to 0}\; \frac{1}{x}\ln\left(\tan(\pi/4 + x)\right)$$

As $x \to 0$, we have $\tan(\pi/4 +x) = \tan(\pi/4) = 1$, and with that $\ln(1) = 0$. So the whole situation is $\frac{0}{0}$ inside that limit, which means we should use L'Hospital. For that, we differentiate the upper and lower part of the fraction with respect to $x$ and obtain through using the chain rule $(f \circ g)' = f'(g) \cdot g'$ twice:

$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\ln(\tan(\pi/4 + x))\right) = \frac{1}{\tan(\pi/4 + x)}\cdot \sec^2(\pi/4 + x)$$

(I encourage you to do this calculation yourself, you know that $\frac{d}{dx} \ln(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ and $\frac{d}{dx} \tan(x) = \sec^2(x)$)

So now we have

$$\lim_{x \to 0}\; \frac{1}{x}\ln\left(\tan(\pi/4 + x)\right) = \lim_{x \to 0}\; \frac{\frac{1}{\tan(\pi/4 + x)}\cdot \sec^2(\pi/4 + x)}{1} = \frac{\frac{1}{1}\cdot 2}{1} = 2$$
Which then means

$$\lim_{x \to 0}\; e^{\frac{1}{x}\ln\left(\tan(\pi/4 + x)\right)} = e^2$$

So in whole that means that the upper left part of the original fraction

$$\lim_{x \to 0}\; \frac{\tan(\pi/4 + x)^{1/x} - e^2}{x^2}$$

goes to $e^2$ and so we have again a sitation of $\frac{e^2 - e^2}{0} = \frac{0}{0}$, which means to solve this you have to use L'Hospital. Since there is $x^2$ in the denominator, you'll have to use L'Hospital twice.

$$\lim_{x \to 0}\; \frac{\tan(\pi/4 + x)^{1/x} - e^2}{x^2} = \lim_{x \to 0}\; \frac{\frac{d}{dx}\left(\tan(\pi/4 + x)^{1/x} - e^2\right)}{2x} = \; ... \;$$

If you did it right, the final answer will be $\frac{4e^2}{3}$. However I find that the first and second derivative of that $\tan(\pi/4+x)^{1/x}$ expression look very ugly.. Maybe someone else will come along and show you a better way, but this way also definetly works.